# Git: How to merge/update parts of a branch from/to main?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I'm a git newbie, and this is what I currently have:

```
master: A -- B -- C
          \
           \
branch:      X -- Y
```

1. How do I Update commit Y with
   changes from B and C?

   Is this simply: `git fetch machine
   master; git merge machine/master`?
2. Push changes of certain files from Y to C?

Comment: I tried a `git pull --rebase machine; git push machine` and got rejections stating that both master and branch were non-fast-forward updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1:

```
git rebase master branch
```

This will result in

```
master: A -- B -- C
                   \
                    \
branch:              X' -- Y'
```

For 2 (while `master` is checked out):

```
git cherry-pick -n Y
```

This will apply changes from Y to your working tree and you may amend C with the changes you want.

See [git-rebase(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) and [git-cherry-pick(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html).

Comment: Thanks, you got me started on the right track.  One thing I wanted to point out is that for me to merge changes from Y' to C, I need to have master checked out before calling `git cherry-pick -n Y'` and not vice versa.